# JavaScript Object Conundrum

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to improve my terrible JavaScript skills by using objects rather than just getting by with globals and random sets of functions. My PHP framework until now used two files for any given (set of) page(s)... `functions.js` and `ajax.js`. I want to keep the separation, but use objects to achieve the same result.

If I have an object...

```
var testJS = {

    init: function(options) {
        var defaultSettings = {
            someOption: false,
            fadeLogo: false
        },

        settings = $.extend({}, this.defaultSettings, options),

        base = this;

        // call ajax function...
        ajax.doSomething();

    },

    somethingElse: function() {
        // whatever
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    testJS.init();
});
```

And then I create an `ajax` object...

```
var ajax = {
    doSomething: function(some_var) {
        $.post("Ajax.class.php", {"mode": 'doSomething', 'some_var': some_var}, function(data) {
            something = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#someId').html(something);

            // call somethingElse function from testJS

        });
    }
}
```

My question seems really dumb...

How do I call (if I can) the `somethingElse` function from the `ajax` object? It seems like it should be available.

Comment: If you want to do OO-js, read up on prototyping. Your dictionaries aren't really OO, f.i. how do you access the instance (`this`).

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yeah, I realized this. I'm reading up on better ways to do things. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only have a single instance of the object, you can just use the global variable that contains that instance:

```
testJS.somethingElse();
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for (for now), and bizarrely, what I tried. The first time it failed and I'm wondering if I fat-fingered it, or if it was never saved, or cached, or something. Anyway, it ultimately worked once I slowed down. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create a new *class*, not just an object. Then you could build a new `testJS` object inside your `ajax` callback.

```
function testJS() {
        this.init = function(options) {
            var defaultSettings = {
                    someOption: false,
                    fadeLogo: false
            };

            this.settings = $.extend({}, this.defaultSettings, options);

            var base = this;

            // call ajax function...
            ajax.doSomething();

        };

        this.somethingElse = function() {
            // whatever
        };
}
```

Then, inside the `ajax` callback:

```
var myTestJS = new testJS({ /* Your options here */ });
myTestJS.somethingElse();
```

I like this better than the other answer because, while the *constructor* for this object is still global, the object itself only exists inside the scope of the callback.  If you want the global behavior, you can still use this method. Just call the constructor outside the callback.

### Edit

The way I defined the `init` function above, your `base` variable isn't going to be able to do anything. I should declare it like this:

```
function testJS() {
    var base = this;
    ...
```

And then remove the `var base = this;` line inside `init`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, ultimately I want to create a new class. Sometimes it's easiest to get a thing working as simply as possible, and make improvements later on. This is one of those scenarios. Thanks for your answer.